# Mongodb compound index to Kibana elasticsearch

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, kibana, compound-index

I am facing a problem trying to setup a dashboard on Kibana, from a mongoDB database.

The problem happens with the compound index. I have a collection in mongoDB with a compound index:

```
sale : {"_id" : {"date" : Date, 
                 "country" : String, 
                 "game_id" : String }, 
        "field_1" : String, 
        "field_n" : String}
```

I am trying to generate a Kibana dashboard using the date that is inside the _id field of the mongoDB document.

To access from Kibana to the mongoDB database I have used the mongo-connector elastic2, everything seems to work as I can see all the fields correctly in Kibana as well as the documents. But the _id is not interpreted, and it appears as an String instead of the 3 fields.

```
_id:{'game_id': 'com.id.game', 'date': datetime.datetime(2016, 6, 22, 0, 0), 'country': 'DZ'}
```

What I want is to make Kibana knows that _id is not an String, that is an String (game_id), a date (date) and an String (country) and let me use the date field as a field for the reports, but I did not succeed so far.

Does anyone know how should I do it?, 
Thank you very much in advance.

Comment: _id is reserved key for id of the document. ES allows string, integer types not json objects for this field.

Comment: I know it, that is why it converts my structure of date, country and game_id in a plain String, but, how can I do to get my fields (date, country and game_id) back?,

Comment: then i will suggest to map _id field to some other field in elastic. check my answer

Answer (score 2):

According to the official [documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-id-field.html) of elastic _id is reserved keyword for each type where it represent unique identifier for each document. _id along with _index, _type, _uid are [meta-fields](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/mapping-fields.html) for a type.

If you want to retain your _id json object, you can map this _id in mongo to some new field in elastic using mongo-elastic namespace configuration like [here](https://github.com/mongodb-labs/mongo-connector/wiki/Configuration-Options#docmanagersindexargs).

```
{
  "namespaces": {
    "include": ["document_type._id"],
    "mapping": {
      "document_type._id": "document_type.mongo_id"
    }
  }
}
```

or command like `-n company.employees -g company.new_employees`

Thanks

Comment: Thank you for your answer, I have tried your solution, but there are two comments on it:

 - It seems to be deprecated since version 2.5.0. 
 - I have tried with the way it should be since v.2.5.0, something like:

      "namespaces": {
  "<database>.<collection>._id" : {
                       "rename" :  "<database>.<collection>.mongo_id"
               }
 }

But I could not make it work, It works for renaming collections but not fields, thank you very much

Comment: Yeah i remeber sometime last year elastic depreciated river plugins and its support. i will try to suggest you another solution later. Thanks

Comment: Thank you very much, I have achieved something similar to a solution, is to modify the elastic2-doc-manager, it is not a big deal, but I really would like to find a better solution.

Comment: @bracana Could you please post a quick answer on how you did it with elastic2-doc-manager? I'm kind of lost! Thanks in advance!